# Jasper Server import export error while installation

Tags: jasperserver

I have an error while installing Jasper Server. At the end of the installation sugarcrm database is created succesfully but when Jasper Server starts importing something is giving error as follows.

```
Warning: Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete
correctly
 Error running /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.2/apache-ant/bin/ant import-ce
-DimportFile=install_resources/export/js-catalog :
BUILD FAILED
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.2/buildomatic/bin/import-export.xml:235: The
following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.2/buildomatic/bin/import-export.xml:158: Java
returned: 255

Total time: 24 seconds
```

I'm using Linux - Xubuntu 12.10 and my java version is

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, this issue related to my hostname.

first I got my hostname using:

```
hostname
```

Then I updated my hosts file:

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

to include my hostname. eg. if my hostname was `bobs-server`

I added:

```
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost bobs-server
```

I then restarted my server, and ran the installation of Jasper again.